# In Drupal 8, how to make users fill out a form with their contact info before downloading a pdf?

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-webform

I've been asked to edit a functionality in our website, where a user click on a link to download a PDF file.

What is needed exactly is that the user must be redirected to a form to fill some information (fname,lname,email,mobile) and once submit the information, the user will be redirected to the download page or the file itself.

can you please advise ! I am so new to Drupal.
Drupal version we use is 8.

Comment: Add details to the session, then if details exist in the session, download, else show form.

Comment: Really ????????

Comment: It's not a drupal specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this module this provide the feature to open form on file click

https://www.drupal.org/project/file_utility